# How to change the 'Line and Clustered Chart' Bar color based on the Measure value in Power Bi report

Tags: powerbi, visualization

I want to differentiate the color of the below line chart bar based on the 2 measures value.

[enter image description here] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiig0.png)

Tried with if clause but for the measure, how to write the DAX not sure.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Provide the code of what you have tried, share a little more info on how you want the colour to change.